# Positive free particle Dirac equation

Tags: particle-physics, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I've been set the task of showing that:

$$
\bar{\psi^{s}}\psi^{s}=2m
$$
For s=0,1. Where:
$$
\psi^{0,1}=\sqrt{|E|+m}\begin{pmatrix}\chi^{0,1}\\ \frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m}\chi^{0,1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where $\chi^{0}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\chi^{1}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

**Now, this is what I have so far:**

Let $a$ be any spinor; then, by definition $\bar a\equiv a^\dagger \gamma^0$, where $\dagger$ stands for hermitian conjugation: transpose + complex conjugation: $a^\dagger=(a^T)^*$. Therefore:
\begin{align*}
\bar{\psi^{s}}\psi^{s}=&\,e^{-ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}e^{ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}(|E|+m)
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & \frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0 \\ 
\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m} \\\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\bar{\psi^{s}}\psi^{s}=&\,(|E|+m)
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&-\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m}&0\\0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\
0 \\ 
\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m} \\\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\\\
\therefore\,\bar{\psi^{s}}\psi^{s}=&\left[(|E|+m)-(|E|+m)\left(\frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m}\right)^{2}\right]
\end{align*}

Essentially it is at this point where I am not sure where to go to reduce this obtain the value of $\bar{\psi^{s}}\psi^{s}=2m$. I'm assuming I have done everything correctly up to this point! Please advise...

Comment: That it must be a multiple of the mass is obvious, because it is the only Lorentz invariant scalar that one can construct from the Dirac Lagrangian. I will try to clear it up to get the right coefficient in front.

Answer (score 0):

You have done all the hard steps, what remains is to remember that $(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{\sigma})^2=\vec{p}^2=E^2-m^2$ so that
\begin{align}
(|E|+m) - (|E|+m)\left(\frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}{E+m}\right)^2 &=
(|E|+m) - (|E|+m)\frac{\vec{p}^2}{(E+m)2}\\
&= (|E|+m) - (|E|+m)\frac{(|E|+m )(|E|- m)}{(E+m)2} \\
&= (|E|+m) - (|E|-m) \\
&=2m
\end{align}

Comment: Yeh I got this as well. Perfect!